# How to get the data from an observable stream

Tags: angular, rxjs

What is the best way to access the data from an observable stream when I need to access it in an Angular component?  I'm aware I can use an async pipe in the template but I need to access the data in the actual component.

So far I've extracted the data to a new variable with either a tap or subscribe but I'm just curious if I'm missing an easier or more concise way to do it. If not, is there a preferred method between tap and subscribe?

```
//assume db.getBook() returns an observable with a book object
this.subscription = db.getBook("153").pipe(   
   tap(book => this.book = book).subscribe()

//or

this.subscription = db.getBook("153").subscribe(book => this.book = book)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.pipe` method is used to chain observable operators and you will always get your emitted data. In addition, pipe method allows webpack to drop unused operators from the final JavaScript bundle. It makes it easier to build smaller files.

`.tap` transparently performs actions or side-effects, such as logging. It does not modify the stream.

`.subscribe` will be called just one time and is used to subscribe to observable response. Moreover, we can put response into some variable to display it into the view.

It is better to use `async` pipe for template:

```
<option *ngFor="let item of items$ | async">
     {{ item?.name }}
</option>
```

For assigning data from the backend, you can use `subscribe()` method:

```
this.yourService.getYourData()
    .subscribe(val => 
       this.items = val
    );
```

[The comment of source code of `tap()` method says:](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/tap.ts)

> This operator is useful for debugging your Observables for the correct
>   values  or performing other side effects.
>
> Note: this is different to a `subscribe` on the Observable. If the
>   Observable returned by `tap` is not subscribed, the side effects
>   specified by the Observer will never happen. `tap` therefore simply
>   spies on existing execution, **it does not trigger an execution to
>   happen like `subscribe` does**.

So it is better to use `subscribe` method to assign data because:

- Your final JavaScript bundle will be more light weight and will not have `tap`method
- If Observable returned by `tap` is not subscribed, the side effects
  specified by the Observer will never happen. So in any way, you need to call `subscribe` method. So there is no need to use `tap` method if you want just assign data

Comment: That makes a lot of sense and is probably the best explanation I've heard yet.  Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @mattc19  I am really glad that  it is helpful to you!:)

Comment: @StepUp , suggetsion on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172059/after-getting-the-response-from-post-api-call-an-error-is-thrown-pipe-is-n , thanks